# A puzzle about vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When beginning to study the notion of vector space using the book"linear algebra and its applications" of D.C.Lay,the book give an example of vector space.It says all continuous functions on the interval [a,b] could be a vector space. Shouldn't a element of vector space be a vector?Why a function in the case above?

Comment: Once you start with (abstract) vector spaces in general, you should let go the physical interpretation of a vector as a geometrical object, e.g. "an arrow". Look at the definition of a vector space (without thinking about your previous notions of vectors) and then consider "vector" as a new object: *an element of a vector space*. A vector space could then be the continuous functions on [a,b], the elements ("vectors") are then functions.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on your definition of a vector. I assume when you think of a vector you think about something like $(1,2)$ or $(1,\pi,6,3.3)$ and the associated geometric meanings.

Another way to define a vector is a vector is any element of a vector space. Look at the definition of a vector space does it specify that the vectors must be like the form above? No it doesn't and there is no reason why they should be.

For example we can define vector spaces over sets of polynomials where the vectors are polynomials and similarly we can define vector spaces of matrices.

You must get used to thinking about vectors in this new way and appreciate it.

It is often more convenient and meaningful to think about vectors this way as it becomes easier to work with. For example if we considered only the geometrical interpretation then we would not really be able to interpret any vectors above $3$ dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

In linear algebra, an important concept is abstracting concepts of its fundamentals. Typically, you may have thought of a vector to have specific `magnitude` and `length` and fit some sort of pre-conceived definition. In the study of linear algebra, this notion does not typically exist. We can abstract this idea and apply it to many objects, so long as it fits with our well-defined rules for what is a "vector space" and a "vector" (in the most basic terms, a set of mathematical objects that abide by certain properties we have decided on).

A matrix is a vector, a number ($5, 2.1, 4$) is a vector. In fact, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are a vector space. The well-defined rules (axioms) can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of a (continuous) real-valued function on $[a,b]$ as an 'uncountable-tuple' where each 'component' is indexed by a real number in $[a,b]$.

Or conversely, you can think of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a function from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $f(i)=$ the $i$-th component of the vector.